solve differential equation and put the result in terms of the input and/or the derivatives of the input
I have the following second-order linear differential equation:
$$ f(t) = y''(t) + r^2y(t)$$
where:

$f(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions of time $t$
$r$ is a constant
$f(t)$ is assumed to be a periodic function

I am seeking a way to express $y(t)$ in terms of $f(t)$ and/or its derivatives ($f'(t)$, $f''(t)$, etc.) and/or its indefinite integral ($\int f(t) dt$).
In other words, I would like to find a solution for $y(t)$ that depends only on the unknown function $f(t)$, its derivatives, its integrals, and the constant $r$. This would allow me to calculate $y(t)$ given the periodic function $f(t)$ and the value of $r$.
Any help or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. If there are any additional constraints or assumptions needed to find a solution, please let me know.
Edit 1: Based on the comments, I arrived at a possible approach
$$
y(t)=-y_1 \int \frac{y_2 f(t)}{W\left(y_1, y_2\right)} d t+y_2 \int \frac{y_1 f(t)}{W\left(y_1, y_2\right)} d t
$$
Provided that $f(t)$ has the form of
$$f(t)=\sum V_n\cos(n\omega t)$$
I tried to find the explicit expression of $y$ in terms of $f,f',f'',\int f dt$, but without success.
Edit 2: I've finally reached a more or less compact form based on Green's functions and the Wronskian:
$$
y(t)=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\sin\left[r(t-s)\right]}{r}f(s)ds
$$

This is inhomogeneous second-order linear differential equation with constant coefficients for $y$. There is plenty of ressources about this stuff everywhere. Basically, solve the characteristic equation for the homogeneous solution and use the method of variation of parameters for the particular solution.

I've edited the question to be more concise and clear. the idea is to get a symbolic expression for $y(t)$

Variation of parameters provides an explicit integral representation of $y$ in terms of $f$ https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx
